# Solve the inequality $\sqrt x+\sqrt{x+1}>\sqrt 3$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, radicals

Solve the inequality $\sqrt x+\sqrt{x+1}>\sqrt 3$.

I want to make sure my method is correct:

The condition is that $x\geq 0$

$x+2\sqrt x\times \sqrt{x+1} +x+1>3$

$2\sqrt{x(x+1)}>2-2x$

$4x(x+1)>4-8x+4x^{2}$

$4x^{2}+4x>4-8x+4x^{2}$

$12x>4$

$x>\frac{1}{3}$

$x\in (\frac{1}{3},\infty)$

I know my final solution is fine, but is everything written properly? Should I put $\iff$ at the beginning of each row?

Comment: A $\iff$ would not be correct as you are squaring the equation, and $y=x^2$ is a many-one function.

Comment: In step three how do you know that 2-2x >= 0 or that 2-2x < 0 but |2-2x| < 2\sqrt{x(x+1)?

Comment: It might just be me, but I think worry about $\iff$.  Sometimes the conclusions will only go one way.  You will have to worry about addding extraneous information, especially when you square. The results of which will certainly *not* be an if and only if.

Answer (score 3):

Over its domain (the set of non-negative real numbers) the function $f(x)=\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x+1}$ is an increasing function, since it is the sum of two non-negative increasing functions. It follows that $f(x)>\sqrt{3}$ holds as soon as $x>x_0$, where $x_0$ is the only positive number such that
$$ \sqrt{x_0}+\sqrt{x_0+1} = \sqrt{3}.\tag{1} $$
$x_0=\frac{1}{3}$ is clearly a solution of $(1)$, hence the given inequality holds for $\color{red}{\large x>\frac{1}{3}}$.

Comment: I guess you meant  $ \sqrt{3} $  and not  $ 3 $ .

Comment: @SylvainJulien: sure, thanks. Now fixed.

Answer (score 2):

We have

$x\geq 0$ .

then

$\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x+1}>\sqrt{3}  \implies$

$\sqrt{x+1}>\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{x}   \implies $

$x+1>3+x-2\sqrt{3x}  \implies$

$\sqrt{3x}>1 \implies  x>\frac{1}{3}$

In the other direction,

$x>\frac{1}{3}  \implies$

$\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{x}>\sqrt{\frac{4}{3}}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}} =\sqrt{3}$

Qed.

Comment: But what if $\sqrt{3} - \sqrt{x}$ is negative? Then we can't square both sides of the inequality, let alone use the $\iff$ sign.

Comment: If it is negative, the inequality is satisfied since $\sqrt{x+1}\geq 0$.

Comment: Yeah, but you have to explicitly mentioned that. Otherwise you're just squaring, which might not be true after all.

Comment: What @Stefan4024 is getting at is that 1 > -2, but squaring both sides doesn't preserve the inequality.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is fine and correct, and you can write it more concise with key steps. In the end, you can simply write $x > 1/3$ without re-write it as $x \in (1/3, \infty)$.

Answer (score 1):

You've made a mistake by assuming that $2 - 2x \ge 0$, when squaring in the second row. To fix this consider the two cases when $x < 1$ and $x \ge 1$.

This will enable you to add the $\iff$ signs, which you're required, as otherwise you have proven that $\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{x+1} > \sqrt{3} \implies x > \frac 13$ instead of $x > \frac 13 \implies \sqrt{x} + \sqrt{x+1} > \sqrt{3}$

---

Assume that $x > 1$. Then we have that $2-2x < 0 < 2\sqrt{x(x+1)}$, so the inequality is true for any $x \ge 1$.

On the other side when $x < 1$ you can continue in your way and you will get that $x \in \left(\frac 13,1\right)$. Now combining the answers you will get that the solution set is $\left(\frac 13,\infty\right)$

Comment: if $x\geq 1$ then I have $4x(x+1) < 4-8x+4x^{2}$. I change the inequality sign?

Comment: @Now_now_Draco_play_nicely You can quickly discard the case $x\ge 1$, as the RHS is negative, but the LHS is positive. It's a trivial thing, but you have to be careful about it.

Comment: I'm really confused now. Can you write out how you would solve this problem step by step?

Comment: @Now_now_Draco_play_nicely You can check now

Comment: Let me ask you just one more thing if I had for example $2\sqrt{x(x+1)}<2-2x$ then I wouldn't need to check for $x\geq 1$ since on the RHS I would have a non-negative expression?

Comment: @Now_now_Draco_play_nicely I mean you have to split the solution in two cases, but as in the actual solution you can easily discard the case when $x \ge 1$ and then continue working with the other case $x <1$

Answer (score -1):

Note that $\sqrt{\frac13}+\sqrt{\frac13+1}=\sqrt{3}$ . The inequality  follows trivially.

Comment: Also, the same argument is essentially given by Jack D'Aurizio, but in an answer of much higher quality.

Comment: @wythagoras it doesn't.  I am comfortable with your edit.

Comment: @wythagoras I was not aware of his solution. I am not comfortable with an intersubjective standard of quality.